# aggrid community Downloader Class not available in v22.0.0+

Tags: excel, download, ag-grid, angular9

I was using aggrid 21.1.0 with Angular 8.  In one of my components I use the Downloader class gotten from 
'ag-grid-community' in this way

```
import { GridOptions, Downloader, ExcelExportParams} from 'ag-grid-community';
```

and used in the code to Download a excelfile : (previously prepared)

```
 const downloader = new Downloader();
    downloader.download(
      `${fileName}.xls`,
      new Blob(
        [ sheet ],
        { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' },
      ),
    );
```

I am migrating to Angular 9,  and I have to upgrade to ag-grid to 22.0.0+  due incompatibility libraries,  but this new version of aggrid has changed drastically some libraries and now I can't use the Downloader class.

Where can I find now this functionality? should I take it from other library (no aggrid)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file path has been changed since `v22.0.0`

You will be able to get it from `@ag-grid-community/csv-export`
Have a look the documentation: [ag-Grid Modules](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-modules/)

> Version 22.0.0 changes the way ag-Grid is made available by providing functionality in modules, allowing you to pick and choose which features you require, resulting in a smaller application size overall.

Comment: thanks Paritosh,  I had done that,  BUT i did not add that module as dependency..  what is required in 22.0.0+ version...

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@ag-grid-community/csv-export": "22.0.0"
}